# Dimensionality reduction for feature extraction when missing some feature values

Tags: feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction, missing-data

I have two questions:

1-Which method is appropriate for dimensionality reduction for feature extraction when missing some feature values?

2-Which textbook is the best source for the answer in (1)?

Comment: I am of the opinion that most dimension reduction techniques cannot handle missing features

Answer (score 0):

Denoising autoencoders will be your bet in this case. I don't have a book handy for this case. They are good at reconstruction and calculate a good latent representation.  Just replace your missing feature with the mean or a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for probabilistic PCA, I heard [somewhere](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-methods-in-machine-learning/lecture/bxZYK/probabilistic-pca) that it can perform well with missing data.